# How to calculate public key for TLS key exchange using OpenSSL functions?

Tags: c++, openssl, x25519

I'm learning TLS 1.3 scheme and trying to implement basic handshake steps in C++ without using ready wrappers from OpenSSL such as `SSL_accept` or `SSL_do_handshake`. The project already uses OpenSSL for common crypto operations, so I would like not to link it with any other crypto libraries where the x25519 calculation is more obvious than in OpenSSL. So...

there are two buffers:

```
unsigned char private_key[32];
RAND_bytes(private_key, 32);

unsigned char public_key[32];
memset(public_key, 0, 32);
```

Which method(s) of OpenSSL should I use to fill `public_key` buffer with bytes computed from `private_key` using x25519 algo (copying and allocating as less as possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `EVP_PKEY`  object using the function `EVP_PKEY_new_raw_private_key` as described here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_new_raw_private_key.html

```
    EVP_PKEY key = EVP_PKEY_new_raw_private_key(EVP_PKEY_X25519, NULL, private_key, sizeof(private_key));
    if (key == NULL)
        /* Error */;
```

You can then obtain the public key bytes using the function `EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key` as described on the same page as above:

```
    size_t publen = sizeof(public_key);
    if (!EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key(key, public_key, &publen))
        /* Error */;
```